# How to get insertBatch() with checkbox in codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

How to get the checkbox data?
This is my view

```
<form method="post" action="<?= current_url();?>" >
<?php foreach($checklist as $item) : ?>
<ul>
  <li>
     <input type="hidden" name="name[]" value="<?= $item->name; ?>">
     <div>
        <label><?= $item->name; ?><label>
        <input type="hidden" value="0" name="status=[]>
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="status[]">
     </div>
  </li>
</ul>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

this is my controller

```
public function checklist() {
if($this->request->getMethod() === 'post') {
$name = $this->request->getPost('nama');
$status = $this->request->getPost('status');
 foreach($name as $key => $value) {
  $checklist[] = [
   'name' => $name[$key],
   'status' => $status[$key] 
  ];
}
$this->model->insertBatch($checklist);

return view('data',$data);
}
```

how to get the status if checked it get double array?

Comment: You'll want to check all your typos first... i.e. name{] aint right and should be name[]. Missing end double quote on name="status=[]>. This code shouldn't even run.

Comment: And $thhis is wrong - please read over your code and fix these obvious errors before posting a question.

Comment: i have fixed my typos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is a multi-item list with an item key. I assume **$item['id']** is a unique key.

View

```
<?php
    $checklist = [['id'=>1,'name'=>'Test name 1','status'=>1],
                ['id'=>2,'name'=>'Test name 2','status'=>0],
                ['id'=>3,'name'=>'Test name 3','status'=>1],
                ['id'=>4,'name'=>'Test name 4','status'=>0],
                ['id'=>5,'name'=>'Test name 5','status'=>0]];
?>
<pre>
<?=print_r($checklist)?>
</pre>
<form method="post" action="<?= current_url()?>" >
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($checklist as $item) : ?>
        <li>
            <input type="hidden" name="name[<?=$item['id']?>]" value="<?=$item['name']?>">
            <div>
                <label><?=$item['name']?><label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="status[<?=$item['id']?>]"<?=$item['status']?' checked':''?>>
            </div>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </ul>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
getPost
<pre>
<?php 
    if(isset($getPost))
        print_r($getPost);
?>
</pre>
return
<pre>
<?php 
    if(isset($return))
        print_r($return);
?>
</pre>
```

Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $checklist = [];
    if($this->request->getPost()) {
        $getPost = $this->request->getPost();
        $status = $this->request->getPost('status');
        foreach($getPost['name'] as $key => $value) {
              $checklist['return'][] = [
               'name'   => $value,
               'status' => isset($status[$key])?1:0];
        }
        $checklist['getPost'] = $this->request->getPost();
        // $this->Model->insertBatch($checklist);
    }
    return view('test',$checklist);
}
```

The final result [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cR3xU.png)